# Copying AWS RDS SQL Server stored procedure result to S3 bucket

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sql-agent-job

Does anyone know if it is possible to execute a SQL Server Agent job in a AWS RDS SQL Server database to export the results (an XML string) into a designated S3 bucket?

Comment: According to this.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html probably not

Comment: Thanks for the comment Nick.McDermaid. I am a little confused, what from the link makes you think that it is not possible?

Comment: The exclusions listed in that site made me think it wasn't possible but then I looked up `sp_send_dbmail` and it appears to work - read this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/powering-up-database-mail-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-how-under-armour-runs-database-mail-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/

Comment: Oh wait.. you wanted to send data to a bucket, not email. Well again according to these constraints: _running command-line scripts by using ActiveX, Windows command shell, or Windows PowerShell are not supported_ , you are going to have a hard time.

Comment: You're going to have to "pull" it out using something external like.. in AWS I think it's called elastic jobs? Where you can run a scheduled script

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is not possible to automatically export the results of an Agent job to S3.

In the end I had to reconfigure the process to have the XML string stored within a table and have a lambda job (python using pyodbc library to connect) execute at a timed interval to get the data out of the DB and into the rest of the process (lambda, API Gateway, SQS and SES).

Not ideal, but got it to work in the end and execute relatively efficiently!